# Bundle.js is not in any folder of my application despite devtool saying the opposite

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

first I am NOT using webpack, its a full MERN stack application.

I run Lighthouse to test my app performance and it says to minify Bundle.js, it has been two hours or more...and still can't find it.

in my index.html there is a line that I am NOT seeing it in my code but appear in the inspector (devtool)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"> </script>
```

i tried to add my workspace to chrome dev tools to locate it, but still doesn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwiby.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it,

When you run npm `start in` any of the examples, an Express server will start which will use Webpack to server `/static/bundle.js` in development.

here it is ...
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1137